Why would the Seasonal Cycle and Orbital Period of a planet not correlate?
My goal is to create a fictional Planet, which has a 4 year-long orbital period around it's star, but still goes through a 1 to 2 year long seasonal cycle like earth. Also the axial tilt should be between 20 and 30 degree.
Is that feasable without a large eccentricity and without a very high axial tilt?
Is it possible that a massive satellite nearby causes an actual axial tilt cycle that lasts shorter than earth's 26'000 something years long?
I'm talking about the tilting cycle according to this article.
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32904/tilting-cycle-vs-orbital-cycle-of-earth

Do I understand this correctly? You want your planet to experience all four seasons, four times during its year? As in all four seasons of Earth's single orbit around its star every quarter orbit of your fictional world? If that's what you're asking, then it might be possible if the world rotates on two axes. What I don't know is if a world can be stable rotating on two axes.

Related, if not even duplicate: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/128505/30492

Not nescessarily 4 times but...
From Earth we know our annual, seasonal cycle. This depends on the angle of incidence of the sunlight. This is subject to a cycle that lasts one year. So it correlates with an orbit around the sun.
However, in my specific scenario, the angle of incidence of solar radiation does not correlate with the central planet's orbit around the star, but instead with the orientation of its axis relative to the star.
An axis is a straight line from pole to pole. And their orientation is also subject to a rotation cycle that differs from the orbital period.

@Ben (a) Clarifications belong in your post, not comments. Never trust comments. [Edit] your post, please. (b) Uranus' axial tilt is nearly 90°. Would that produce the kind of seasonal changes you're interested in? (c) A polar axis that always tilted toward the sun would require the planet to rotate on two axes (although the second axis rotation is just once per year, meaning it's "axially tidally locked" (*cough*)).

Although this question has been marked as a duplicate, my accepted answer here is definitely not an answer to that question.

Fast-spinning star
Achernar (Alpha Eridani) is an example of a star which is much hotter (17152 K) at the poles than at the equator, and much bigger as seen from the poles than from the equator, because it is spinning very fast.  A red dwarf star orbits it at 7.35 AU every 7 years.  This is a little too long for your requirements, but if a fictional star *chernar will do, you can simply move the red dwarf in a bit.  The habitable zone for Achernar is around 4 AU because it is a very bright blue star.  So in our case the planet orbits, nice and stable, tidally locked to the red dwarf, receiving a certain minimum of light from it on the near side, but the far side depends on *chernar for light.  If the red dwarf in our case has a polar orbit relative to *chernar, the light is much brighter twice per year.  At these times, the planet might orbit so that *chernar is straight overhead from the far side once a day, or it might be on the horizon, or anything between.  So for example, *chernar might dim as the red dwarf moves to a more equatorial position, but at the same time it rises in the farside sky.  Balancing these effects allows you to set up a complex profile of seasons to meet your needs.

Wish I could upvote this more than once. In fact, it's given me an idea for an alternative answer along the same lines...... :)

I forgot to address the axial tilt.  A fast-spinning star actually drags space around it, so it causes somewhat non-Keplerian orbits of planets.  I'm not sure how that interfaces with the axis.  But I assume it puts a strong torque on the planet, so it probably could have much less than 26000 year precession ... how much less I have no idea.
